# Unable to load several versions of AppEngine Project and Seeing HardDeadLineExceeded Exceptions

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Suddenly, without warning, my AppEngine project would no longer load in the browser. http://my.loopto.do.  This also is happening with older versions of the application.  Below is the 500 error.

I know what a DeadlineExceededException is. What I don't understand is why this is happening, even on versions that were previously working fine with no problems. The log, turned all the way up to ALL, doesn't seem to shed any light on what the problem is.

Another interesting point is that the same codebase, when uploaded to a different appspot domain, loads without issues.

-Thus, the code runs on one appspot domain but not another, isolating the code as a constant.
- Additionally, older versions that were previously working on the broken appspot domain are also experiencing the HardDeadlineExceededError.
- The application also loads fine on localhost, using the latest SDK 1.6.2.1.

I assume this is an Appengine problem, because the log doesn't show where exactly *my* code is breaking.

**What do I need to do to resolve this issue?**

**Here is the StackTrace:**

```
2012-02-23 12:50:06.744 /loop/?t=1330030019399 500 187376ms 1kb Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.112 Safari/535.1
50.43.101.83 - user.name [23/Feb/2012:12:50:06 -0800] "GET /loop/?t=1330030019399 HTTP/1.1" 500 1309 "http://0-9-2012-2-23.loopaback.appspot.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.112 Safari/535.1" "0-9-2012-2-23.loopaback.appspot.com" ms=187376 cpu_ms=560 api_cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.015809     loading_request=1 pending_ms=13 exit_code=104     instance=00c61b117c1a26c7b1ad046194db91806cb9d7
W 2012-02-23 12:50:06.616

Failed startup of context com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.RuntimeAppEngineWebAppContext@fe2558{/,/base/data/home/apps/s~loopaback/0-9-2012-2-23.357026711120155741}
com.google.apphosting.api.DeadlineExceededException: This request (c567eadbd5f794fd) started at 2012/02/23 20:47:09.524 UTC and was still executing at 2012/02/23 20:49:56.454 UTC.
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getNextEntry(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$400(ZipFile.java:57)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$2.nextElement(ZipFile.java:342)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$2.nextElement(ZipFile.java:328)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile$1.nextElement(JarFile.java:240)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile$1.nextElement(JarFile.java:235)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.addJarEntriesToEntryMap(URLClassPath.java:813)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.access$1600(URLClassPath.java:723)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:900)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpenSynchronized(URLClassPath.java:846)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(URLClassPath.java:838)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(URLClassPath.java:785)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(URLClassPath.java:743)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:412)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:395)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:371)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.findResource(URLClassPath.java:201)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findResource(URLClassLoader.java:376)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.UserClassLoader.findResource(UserClassLoader.java:723)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:977)
    at org.mortbay.resource.Resource.newSystemResource(Resource.java:203)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configureDefaults(WebXmlConfiguration.java:159)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:202)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:171)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:123)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:422)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
C 2012-02-23 12:50:06.630
Uncaught exception from servlet
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Initialization failed.
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:211)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:171)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:123)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:422)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
I 2012-02-23 12:50:06.702
This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
W 2012-02-23 12:50:06.702
A serious problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. If you see this message frequently, you may be throwing exceptions during the initialization of your application. (Error code 104)
```

Comment: Update: It seems like things are loading ok now. We were down for a few hours. I tagged this question as "bug" so the Appengine developers would see it.

Comment: @Rick - They actually announced they're officially [moving AppEngine community support to StackOverflow](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-java/8zQtq_m9W5w) and will make the Google Group read-only starting March 5th.

Comment: Yeah, I read that.. are you suggesting that there was a lot of support from the google engineers on the google group? :)

Comment: No, but I'll suggest that there's a lot of support *here* already. I see GAE engineers respond to questions all the time on this site. :) Frankly, I find StackOverflow much easier to use and the chances of getting fast, accurate responses is great! I think it's a great move for them and the community.

Comment: I'm getting the same error :(

Comment: For production issues as this one, I'll suggest using the external issue tracker at: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list?can=2&q=Type%3DProduction+&colspec=ID+Type+Component+Status+Stars+Summary+Language+Priority+Owner+Log&cells=tiles if you do not see productions issues like yours file one ;)